# Use Share Charm with Caliburn.Micro for WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

Does anyone know if the caliburn.micro WinRT port already supports the share target contract and how one has to use it?

EDIT: As it turns out, they only support share sourcing so far.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.markermetro.com/2012/08/technical/caliburn-micro-for-winrt-mvvm-magic-pixie-dust-for-everyone/) states that:

> Over the past week *[of August 2nd]* we’ve had some time to port the latest version of
>   this great library to WinRT as well as include some extension points
>   into the functionality of Windows 8 such as the Sharing and Settings
>   charms.

[This article](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/caliburn-micro-on-winrt) states that:

> *[You can implement the Share]* charm simply by having your view model
>   implement the interface `ISupportSharing`.

Comment: well, as it turns out, this only supports the share source contract, but not the share target.